# nomenclature for Python function arguments

Tags: python

```
args = [4,5]
kwargs = {'x': 7}
func(a, b=2, *args, **kwargs)
```

What is the accepted nomenclature for referring to a, b, args, and kwargs?

In particular, fill in the blank here:

```
'a' is a (_blank_) positional argument
'args' contains (_blank_) positional arguments
'b' is a (_blank_) keyword argument
'kwargs' contains (_blank_) keyword arguments
```

I'm looking for something like **(*blank*) = {formal / arbitrary length / actual / variable position / fixed}**

Also please correct me if I'm wrong on the above.

Comment: I'm not sure what semantics you're trying to capture here, but if you replace `blank` with, well, blank -- i.e., nothing -- then all of your sentences seem right to be.  E.g.: `'a' is a positional argument.`

Comment: @mark: Are you trying to articulate the difference between `formal parameters` and `function arguments`?

Comment: I'm trying to disambiguate discussions about function arguments. For example, if 'b' was supposed to be 3 instead of 2, what would someone tell me? "Hey, your keyword argument is incorrect" sounds ambiguous to me.

Comment: @DanielPryden aren't all of [a,b,args,kwargs] considered function arguments? I'm making a call to func in the code example.

Comment: @mark: I would say that `a`, `2`, `[4,5]`, and `{'x': 7}` are the function's arguments.  `b` is one of the function's formal parameters.  For all I know from the call site, the function could have been declared as `def func(foo, b, *spam, **eggs)`.  Basically, a function's *arguments* are *values*, but its *formal parameters* are *variables*.  Generally, if there is a problem with an argument, you report the error using the name of the corresponding formal parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Much of what you're looking for can be found in [the Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

From left to right:

- `a` is a positional argument.
- `b=3` is a positional argument with a default value of 3.
- `*args` is an arbitrary argument list, unpacked as a tuple.
- `**kwargs` is a keyword argument, unpacked as a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As Edward Loper already described, your terms are correct. You can only be more specific:

1. 'a' is *the first required* positional argument.
2. 'args' passes *illegal* positional arguments. (You know, since you use it after a keyword argument.)
3. 'b' is an *optional* keyword argument… named *b*… with a default value of 2.
4. 'kwargs' passes *arbitrary* keyword arguments.

   ```
   def punk(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
       print a
       print b
       print args
       print kwargs

   a=1; b=2; args = [4,5]; kwargs={'x':7}
   punk(a, b=b, *args, **kwargs)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: punk() got multiple values for keyword argument 'b'
   ```

If you use `args` legally, you could say it is used to pass potentially required and arbitrary positional arguments.

```
>>> punk(a, *args)
1
4
(5,)
{}
```